# ConnectionError when running Redis server inside Docker

Tags: docker, redis

I have the following Python script, `example.py`:

```
import redis
r = redis.Redis()
r.set('a','b')
```

and the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install system-wide dependencies
RUN apt-get -yqq update
RUN apt-get -yqq install python3-dev python3-pip
RUN apt-get -yqq install redis-tools redis-server

RUN pip3 install redis

# Copy application code
ADD . /usr/local/example
WORKDIR /usr/local/example

# Start application
CMD /etc/init.d/redis-server restart \
        && python3 example.py
```

After I build the container (`docker build -t redis-example .`) and run it (`docker run -P -it -d redis-example`), the following stack trace is printed:

```
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 484, in connect
    sock = self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 541, in _connect
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 529, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 667, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 610, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 585, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 489, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

I'm not sure why this *very* simple example is failing in Docker. I'd like to run an instance of a Redis server local to the Docker container.

It does not need to be reachable outside of the container and should be unique to the container.

How can I resolve this exception?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem ! Did you manage to find a solution ?